# Why isn't the article "the" used in "...is a one act play"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

> "Never Never Nest" is **a** one act play.

Why do we use **a** in this sentence? My teacher told  me that when there is something specific we use **the** not **a**. Isn't one act play is specific and shouldn't we be using **the** instead of **a**?

Comment: "A one-act play" is not specific until you have identified it. If you go on to tell us more about 'Never Never Nest', you might say _The play was written by X and first performed in [date]_.

Comment: ***The** one-act play "Never Never Nest" is **a** simple production, easily put on stage in any theatre*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an *Act* is not an *Actor*.  An *Act* is one of the major parts of a play.  Most plays are between one and three acts.  The *acts* are usually further divided into *scenes*. There are many plays that consist of only one act.  That is why we say, *Never Never Nest, is **a** one act play.*

If we were going to say something about Never Never Nest that would single that play out from all other *one act plays* we could use the article **the** to do that.

> Never Never Nest is **the** one act play that makes me laugh out loud.

In the example above, Never Never Nest is still only one of many *one act plays* but I have let the reader know that out of all the one act plays, it is the single play that makes me laugh out loud.  The example implies that there are no other one act plays that make me laugh out loud.

> Never Never Nest is **a** one act play that makes me laugh out loud.

In the example above Never Never Nest still makes me laugh out loud but there could be other one act plays that also make me laugh out loud.

Comment: Yes, except that your final sentence isn't *quite* true. There's no doubt that ***the*** in your first example effectively *forces* the implication that ***no other one-act plays*** make you lol. But using ***a*** instead of ***the*** simply nullifies that implication - it doesn't actually ***assert*** any "negated" version thereof. Maybe it's one of many that make you lol, or maybe it's still the only one that does so; it's just that the indefinite article version is "agnostic" on that front. Switching from ***a*** to ***one*** goes further in that direction, though.